# Какую архитектуру выбрать для движка?

Tags: архитектура, c++, движок

При написании движка (не игрового, функционал хочется шире сделать) возникла следующая развилка:
(в языке c++ интерфейсов нет, но есть абстрактные классы) Мне необходимо применять методы для каждого объекта на сцене (для каждого свои, но есть общие для многих), но можно выделить иерархию.
Например: есть  интерфейс ISceneObject с методом check_сollision(), есть IDrawableSceneObject : ISceneObject с методом draw() и IHuman : IDrawableSceneObject с методом check_hp(). С такой иерархией я вынужден на объекты всех различных интерфейсов хранить ссылки и пробегать несколько раз по одному и тому же объекту:

```
for(int i = 0; i < scene_objects_count; i++)
  scene_objects[i].check_collision();
for (int i = 0; i < draw_scene_objects_count; i++)
  draw_scene_objects[i].draw();
for (int i = 0; i < humans_count; i++)
  humans[i].check_hp();
```

Т.е. я храню лишние ссылки и пробегаю по некоторым объектам по несколько раз.
Есть другое решение: я могу создать один интерфейс для всех, IObject с методом object_life() в котором буду для каждого наследника писать свои необходимые методы. таким образом для объектов из ISceneObject в прошлом примере метод будет:

```
object_life(){
  check_collision();
}
```

а для IHuman:

```
object_life(){
  check_collision();
  draw();
  check_hp();
}
```

и будет достаточно пустить один цикл

```
for (int i = 0; i < objects_cnt; i++)
  objects[i].object_life();
```

Второй способ работает вроде быстрее и меньше памяти ест, но мне кажется он менее красив, хотя в движке, безусловно, важнее всего скорость.
Покритикуйте пожалуйста, может я чего-то не вижу наперёд?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Ваш последний абзац явно говорит о том, что вы в ваших рассуждениях движетесь, следуя принципам `premature optimization.` На эту тему написано столько постов и информации, что, мне кажется, стоит ознакомиться с ней, а начать можно [**отсюда.**](http://insidecpp.ru/antipatterns/premature_optimization/)
- Далее, конкретно по поводу дизайна ваших сущностей:

> - Вариант с `object_life` плох тем, что у вас получается эдакий `God Method.` Он позволяет любому классу, реализующему ваш интерфейс делать **все, что угодно,** поскольку `object_life` — это слишком обширное понятие.
> - Классическим способом разделения логики для сущностей в движках является применение двух методов — `updateState(...)` и `drawOnSurface(...).` При этом подходе происходит отделение логики обновления состояния и, собственно, отображения этого состояния на экране.

- Для того, чтобы преобразовать ваш текущий код к такому подходу, нужно сделать следующее:

> - Вынести логику проверки коллизий в некоторый `helper,` у которого, к примеру, можно будет спросить, пересекаются ли два объекта в некоторый момент времени.
> - Заменить метод `check_hp()` на метод типа `is_dead()` и вынести соответствующую логику в отдельный класс, который будет опрашивать объекты на предмет их состояния и совершать какие-либо действия в том случае, если, например, объект умер.

- Небольшой сниппет для иллюстрации вышенаписанного:

  ```
  struct IEntity
  {
      virtual void updateState(...) = 0;
      virtual void drawOnSurface(std::shared_ptr<Surface> surface) = 0;
  };

  // Here comes our main game loop.
  foreach (std::shared_ptr<IEntity> entity in entities)
  {
      entity->updateState(...);
      entity->drawOnSurface(surface);
  }
  ```

Comment: Про "premature optimization" - иногда наблюдал за собой этот грешок, просто казалось, что в движке каждая лишняя операция на счету(особенно если она часто применяется), что он является некоторым исключением.  
Check_hp естественно глупый пример, такого у меня нет)
Выходит updateState это God method исключая методы отрисовки? 
Ведь у меня может быть много методов(точнее событий), которые надо проверять каждую итерацию для определённого подкласса объектов. Например, проверка если объекты какого-то типа ближе 5 пикселей друг к другу, то делать то-то. Эту проверку тоже выносить в отдельный класс?

Comment: Согласен с @Котик у вас тут слишком низкий уровень абстракции. Вы хотите одновременно проверять столкновения, рисовать и обрабатывать логику при этом наследуя все от одного класса ISceneObject (при таком подходе в частности нельзя отрисовывать два объекта за один проход и никак не учитывается собственно техника которой вы хотите это отрисовать). 

Если в кратце то сначала обрабатываете логику/столкновения. Затем по результатам специальным классом SceneObjectAssembler возвращаете пачку DrawableSceneObject и только потом отрисовывайте её.

Comment: Кстати если вы и вправду так заботитесь о скорости вашего движка в столь критичном месте, то  почему не развернули эти три петли через Duffs device? Больше оптимизации, еще больше.